# Problem with mirror modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror, selection-tools

I have a small issue when trying to merge two objects together

I am trying to add the following selection...

[image]

to be part of the rest of my mesh by using CTRL +J, see below...

[image]

However when I do, it splits the first selection in half, see below in yellow. Is this because the first selection no longer has a mirror modifier applied?

[image]

On a slightly separate note, when I used shift/click to select both objects - shouldn't the first selection still have a darker outline? (see above second image, showing no outline...)

Many thanks

Comment: you need to **apply** the modifier before joining to make the geometry real.

Comment: Grouping or Parenting might be a better option, if you don't want to apply your modifiers at this stage.